# Visually explore Oracle database in Rstudio, but JDBC connection

Tags: r

At my work we have an Oracle database we connect to.  We often use R to query it, with code like this:

```
library(RJDBC)
classpath_name="A:/ojdbc8.jar"

# Create connection driver and open connection
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath=classpath_name)  
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=website.com)(PORT=2879))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdblhs)))", "username", "password")  

rv_protocol_staff<-  dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 
                                "select * From schema.rv_protocol_staff order by protocol_id, created_date")
```

Works great.  Thing is, I'm a visual guy, and I like browsing the schema sometimes.  I tend to use SQL developer for that:

[image]

but I'd love to stay entirely within one application if possible.  Recently I saw Rstudio's connections pane when I was working on an old MS Access database:

[image]

And it got me thinking that'd be really cool to do with our 'main' database.

Well, quick internet search and it seems like Rstudio doesnt really support jdbc in that way:

[image]

**So my question is**

Can I still somehow browse my schema through RStudio?

Thoughts I had for that:

- Connect a different way?  ODBC instead of jdbc?  Is that possible? Or do the database administrators control that?
- Create the connection contract?  Impossible to do as an end user?
- Anything else?